# Is there a way to have multiple Plotly-Dash maps refer to the same animation slider?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to have two plotly.express choropleth maps to be animated at the same time (and for the user to pick whichever date they wish) by using a single time slider, affecting both maps. The closest I got to was this:

[image: Two maps with two sliders]

But instead of two sliders, I want to have just one, which affects both maps at the same time.

I did search for the answer and there are approaches to that for plots [(shown here)](https://community.plotly.com/t/using-one-slider-to-control-multiple-subplots-not-multiple-traces/13955/2), but I did not find them for maps, especially in express as the slider is created automatically so there is no easy way to change it/connect to another slider. I was therefore wondering if there is any elegant and way of using just one slider within express framework, before going into building a separate slider, moving away from the convenience of express maps and finding the events and somehow connecting them to maps. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use a single slider for both the graphs, but you would have to create your own slider component using `dash core components` for example:

```
dcc.Slider(
    id='my-slider',
    min=0,
    max=20,
    step=0.5,
    value=10,
),
```

And then in a callback, have two graph outputs react using the slider input. Some pseudo code:

```
@app.callback([Output('graph1_id', 'figure'), 
           Output('graph2_id', 'figure')],
          Input('my-slider', 'value'))
def change_display(slider_value):
call_fnct_changing_graph(slider_value)
```

Comment: Thanks Syamanthaka, that is a way forward, but this solution on its own does not provide me with the nice animation "play" button, so that I can show the results shown day by day, as an animation. I assume I would need to add all this functionality again myself by defining appropriate functions? It just seems to me like a massive waste to prepare all of this by hand when there is perfectly good express function which already does 95% of work- is that really the only way to prepare something not very complicated like a single slider connected to two maps?

Comment: Then the only other suggestion I can make is to have a `button` named 'Play' which triggers a click of the play button of both the graphs.